# inorder and postorder traversal

Tags: depth-first-search, inorder, postorder

What sense does it make to, say, visit children before parent in inorder and postorder? I understand that inorder, preorder and postorder traversal are just a way to represent a tree. Am I correct?

Comment: Hello, can you accept my answer, please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In-order, post-order, and pre-order are not ways to represent a tree but ways to traverse the tree. Where it gets interesting is the reasons for choosing one traversal over another.

Pre-order traversals are very useful for duplicating nodes and edges to make a complete duplicate of a binary tree. They are also useful for making prefix expressions (from expression trees.

Using post-order traversals while deleting nodes and values can delete an entire binary tree. Similarly, they can also generate a postfix representation of a binary tree.

Finally, in-order traversals are useful for binary search trees because they return values from the underlying set in order.

Answer (score 0):

The **Pre-order**, **In-order**, **Post-order** are three ways to *traverse* a tree.
The above three types of traversal belong to the **Depth First** traversal.

Take the below picture as an example:

[image]

The **Depth First Pre-order**  follows the *Node -> Left_Child -> Right-Child* convention. And if you use it on our current example, you should get:

**A, B, D, E, C**

The **Depth First In-Order** traversal follows the *Left-Child -> Node -> Right-Child* convention. It looks like this:

**D, B, E, A, C**

The **Depth First Post-Order** traversal follows the *Left-Node -> Right-Node -> Node* convention. That's how it looks:

**D, E, B, C, A**

The **Breadth First Level-Order** traversal, is a traversal where you start from the Root Node and go down each level of you tree reading nodes from left to right.
It would look like this:

**A, B, C, D, E**